# Restaring app when device locale changed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a way to make app restart when device language changed , is there any way to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by starting an instance of the app, that will re-open your app once it has closed itself!

You can try using this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( Application.ExecutablePath); // to start new instance of application
this.Close();
```

Comment: i found a way to restart the app by just wrap whole app with a statefull widget then set his state. now im looking for a way listen to locale changing.

Comment: great! So is my answer not answering your question? You can set it as answer so that people know you've found the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to restart the app with just wrapping the whole app with a widget and then set his state .
i'am looking for a way to listen to locale changement .

```
class RestartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  RestartWidget({this.child});

  static restartApp(BuildContext context) {
    final _RestartWidgetState state =
        context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<_RestartWidgetState>());
    state.restartApp();
  }

  @override
  _RestartWidgetState createState() => new _RestartWidgetState();
}

class _RestartWidgetState extends State<RestartWidget> {
  Key key = new UniqueKey();

  void restartApp() {
    this.setState(() {
      key = new UniqueKey();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      key: key,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

and then call :

```
RestartWidget.restartApp(context)
```